# how to find consecutive weeks

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having some trouble trying to find consecutive weeks a product has been sold. I have converted date in to the weeks and assigned a number to it but a lot of them have gapes where there was no sale. How do I find if there was sale for more than 3 weeks?

Current data:

```
Product_ID ProductCategory  WeekNumberOfYear
123        CSF              8
123        CSF              10
456        CSF              1
456        CSF              2
456        CSF              3
456        CSF              4
789        MLI              1
789        MLI              2
789        MLI              3
```

As you can see Product 456 is the only one that was sold consecutively for more than 3 weeks

My output should be:

```
Product_ID ProductCategory  TotalConsecutiveWeeks
456        CSF              4
```

OR

```
Product_ID ProductCategory
456        CSF
```

How can I avoid the non-consecutive sales of 3 or less weeks? Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: do you not have a year column in the table?

Comment: Yeah I can create a year column with date, just how I created NumberofWeek

Comment: I think @VamsiPrabhala is asking because... what happens at 52>1?

Comment: @JacobH Its per year so its going to 1 for the 1st week

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala actually I am only working with 2017 year

Comment: Google islands and gaps. This type of thing has been asked and answered hundreds and hundreds of times.

Answer (score 2):

ok,so you can use a query like below to find all the products which have trended for more than 3 weeks.

Tip: change the 3 in where clause to any number that you want for the least amount of week required for trending
<kbd>**[Working demo](http://rextester.com/WWESCS78082)**</kbd>

```
create table sales (Product_ID int, ProductCategory varchar(10),  WeekNumberOfYear int)
insert into sales values
(123,'CSF',8)
,(123,'CSF',10)
,(456,'CSF',1)
,(456,'CSF',2)
,(456,'CSF',3)
,(456,'CSF',4)
,(789,'MLI',1)
,(789,'MLI',2)
,(789,'MLI',3)
;

; with cte as
(
    select *, 
    idx= WeekNumberOfYear- row_number() over (partition by product_id order by weekNumberOfYear)
    from sales
   )

 select 
 product_id,
 ProductCategory,
 count=count(1) 
 from cte
 group by product_id,ProductCategory,idx 
 having count(1)>3
```